# How to Make Container Width Responsive to Floating Elements Inside

Tags: html, css, width

I'm a student making a website for my assignment and I'm working on a contact form as seen here:
http://www.brightpixelstudios.co.uk/contact/

I'm trying to get the border surrounding the contact form to take up only the width necessary and not 100% of its parent container.

The container has floating elements inside it, would this be what's causing the problem?

Is there any work around I could try?

Thanks in advance,

Will Whitehead

Comment: A normal block element does not respond to the width of its contents, unless you float it (the container that is.) If that is not an option, you could use a table, or simulate a table with CSS.

Comment: I set the container to float and it's width has responded to it's contained elements accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have three options here:

1. set `.wpcf7{ float: left }`
2. set `.wpcf7{ display: table }`
3. or set `.wpcf7{ display: inline-block }`

All of which will cause the contact form to take up the space of its children, and not its parent. It really depends on what you're after or what suits the needs of that particular page.

Comment: Didn't realize inline-block caused the parent container to take on the size of it's elements.  Perfect!